# How to add TTL field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How to add TTL(Time to live) field on some element which is already in collection (MONGODB)

If I have one element (.iso file) in collection like showed below:

```
db.videos.files.find().pretty()
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5400e505559ad1c150a3e489"),
  "chunkSize" : NumberLong(262144),
  "length" : NumberLong(754483200),
  "md5" : "093866b3f0cc342c457217892d841f96",
  "filename" : "GTA.UNDERGROUND.iso",
  "contentType" : null,
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-08-29T20:39:33.019Z"),
  "aliases" : null,
  "metadata" : {
  "description" : "Grand Theft Auto",
  "tags" : [
       "Action",
       "HD"
  ]
}
```

How and I set time to live field in MongoDB for this element ?

Comment: Which is the field you want to be controlled by TTL?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
db.my_collection.update(
       {'_id': ObjectId("5400e505559ad1c150a3e489") },
       {'$set': {'TTL': 549}}, true );
```

Comment: I've done that, but why this element is still in collection - I thought that is suppose to vanish from there (I have set ttl field to 60 sec).
And when I check collection I can see that it is still here